# HaxeFlixel how to not pack assets in one SWF

Tags: flash, haxe, flashdevelop, haxeflixel

I use FlashDevelop and have a HaxeFlixel project with a rather huge assets size.
It is ok for desktop target, but with flash I want to get main swf and assets in separate swf file, that will be loaded inside of program in extra state, with loading dialog, and than switch to usual states.

Can I make 2 swf files with code and assets, and than load second from the first at start (without using external packers)?